# jQuery Mobile: Programmatically show ajax loader

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css, jquery-mobile

I load content with an ajax request and it can take some time till everything (images and text) is loaded and displayed on the page.

I would like to show a loading spinner at the start of the ajax call and hide it when all content is really there.

It tried sth like this, but it doesn't work:

```
$(this).ajaxStart(function() {
 $.mobile.loading('show');
});

$(this).ajaxStop(function() {
 $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

*Update*:

The loader is spinning now, but I still need an event when all content is finally rendered by the browser

Answer (score 3):

Or you can add this into a ajax call:

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
},
complete: function() {
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. In principle its working, but the event "complete" seems to happen too early: I mean, the browser still draws images and the loader already disappeared

Comment: This is because ajax part is over but DOM is still drawing a content.

Comment: Yes, but first tell me, you are using this to dynamically add a content to jquery mobile page?

Comment: Yes there is a listview and I add content like text with .html() to it and also append() some images and so on.

Comment: Great, tell me what page event are you using to load data with ajax? pagebeforeshow maybe?

Comment: it's a function triggered after button click:

function getxxx(mID){
  $.ajax({
  url: "

Comment: Ok, then in case of dynamic listview use $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); after .listview('refresh')

Comment: also listview('refresh') is happening too early

Comment: are you populating only a listview or is there any more content?

Comment: there is more, this is taking the most time: $('.X').html('<a href="#XX"><img src="XXX" width="300" height="200"></a>');

Comment: Ok, in the end, are you using .page() function to restyle whole page?

Comment: The really last thing of the function is $('.X').show().listview('refresh'); If you need more code please tell me

Comment: by the way, the loader is even not spinning.. has this to be configured?

Comment: Then tell me a id of your page and I will send you something to try.

Comment: <div data-role="page" id="filme" data-add-back-btn="true">